# Pass array as individual items in another array

Tags: php, arrays, drupal

I have this array

```
$arr = ['field_event_start_date', 'widget', 0, 'value', '#date_part_order', 3]
```

And I want to convert this into this array in below format

```
$form['field_event_start_date']['widget'][0]['value']['#date_part_order'][3]
```

Trying to append the array to `$form` array.

I have a `$form` array, which contains many fields, and I want to unset a set of fields. The array above, is part of a bigger array. If I take this array, How do I convert this into array like below

```
$form['field_event_start_date']['widget'][0]['value']['#date_part_order'][3]
```

I have tried, implode like this `$form[implode('][', $arr)]` But this always says, undefined index.

Final code I need to run is

```
unset($form['field_event_start_date']['widget'][0]['value']['#date_part_order'][3]);
```

However, there are many like this, which number of depth varying. I need to write a generic function to achieve this.

Comment: instead of unsetting existing array, replace its value.

Comment: For that as well, I need to reach that point which contains the value.
The question is, how do i build the above statement from a given array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 8, you can use [`NestedArray::unsetValue()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21NestedArray.php/function/NestedArray%3A%3AunsetValue/8.3.x) to unset a value is nested arrays. You can also use [`NestedArray::getValue()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21NestedArray.php/function/NestedArray%3A%3AgetValue/8.3.x) and [`NestedArray::setValue()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21NestedArray.php/function/NestedArray%3A%3AsetValue/8.3.x) to get and set value from nested arrays using a array of keys (`$parents`).

Drupal 7 only have [`drupal_array_get_nested_value()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_array_get_nested_value/7.x) and [`drupal_array_set_nested_value()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_array_set_nested_value/7.x). But no `drupal_array_unset_nested_value()`. It can easily be ported from Drupal 8:

```
/**
 * Unsets a value in a nested array with variable depth.
 *
 * This helper function should be used when the depth of the array element you
 * are changing may vary (that is, the number of parent keys is variable). It
 * is primarily used for form structures and renderable arrays.
 *
 * @param array $array
 *   A reference to the array to modify.
 * @param array $parents
 *   An array of parent keys, starting with the outermost key and including
 *   the key to be unset.
 * @param bool $key_existed
 *   (optional) If given, an already defined variable that is altered by
 *   reference.
 *
 * Port of NestedArray::unsetValue() from Drupal 8
 *
 * @see drupal_array_get_nested_value()
 * @see drupal_array_set_nested_value()
 */
function drupal_array_unset_nested_value(array &$array, array $parents, &$key_existed = NULL) {
  $unset_key = array_pop($parents);
  $ref = &drupal_array_get_nested_value($array, $parents, $key_existed);
  if ($key_existed && is_array($ref) && array_key_exists($unset_key, $ref)) {
    $key_existed = TRUE;
    unset($ref[$unset_key]);
  }
  else {
    $key_existed = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

`eval("\$form['".implode("']['", $arr)."']='';");`

Comment: That didn't work. I tried this on CLI.
`php eval("\$form['".implode("']['", ['a', 'b'])."']='';");
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`